# Update data in SQL Server view based on union select

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that I can update using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise version 11.0.6251 Windows NT 6.3 (15063).

However, the view is not allowing me to update it on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise version 11.0.3128 Windows NT 6.2 (9200).

I'm only trying to update one column in the view. (The CreditIssued column)

I have looked to see if there is a way to upgrade SQL Server 11.0.3128 to 11.0.3128, but SQL Server is telling me that I have the latest version, and there is nothing to upgrade.

Is there something I'm missing that will allow me to update the data in the view on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise 11.0.3128

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Credits] AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT
    [g].[SortNbr], 
    [g].[GradeName] + ' ' + (CASE WHEN [g].[PersonID] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE [t].[LastName] + ', ' + [t].[FirstName] END) AS GradeLongName, 
    [m].[MealID],
    [MealDate], 
    [MealLine1], 
    [MealLine2], 
    [MealLine3], 
    [op].[FirstName] + ' ' + [op].[LastName] + ' ' + ISNULL(NULLIF ([op].[UniqueName], ''), '') + ': ' + [Drink] + ' ' + ISNULL(NULLIF ([OrderComment], ''), '') AS OrderText, 
    [gt].[GradeTypeID], 
    [g].[GradeID],
    [o].[OrderID],
    [o].[CreditIssued]
FROM ((([People] AS op 
INNER JOIN ([DrinkOptions] AS do 
INNER JOIN ([Meals] AS m 
INNER JOIN [Orders] AS o 
ON [m].[MealID] = [o].[MealID]) 
ON [do].[DrinkID] = [o].[DrinkID]) 
ON [op].[PersonID] = [o].[PersonID]) 
INNER JOIN [Grades] AS g 
ON [op].[GradeID] = [g].[GradeID]) 
LEFT JOIN [People] AS t 
ON [g].[PersonID] = [t].[PersonID]) 
INNER JOIN [GradeTypes] AS gt 
ON [g].[GradeTypeID] = [gt].[GradeTypeID]
UNION SELECT        
    [g].[SortNbr], 
    [g].[GradeName] + ' ' + (CASE WHEN [g].[PersonID] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE [op].[LastName] + ', ' + [op].[FirstName] END) AS GradeLongName, 
    [m].[MealID],
    [MealDate], 
    [MealLine1], 
    [MealLine2], 
    [MealLine3], 
    [op].[FirstName] + ' ' + [op].[LastName] + ' ' + ISNULL(NULLIF ([op].[UniqueName], ''), '') + ': ' + [Drink] + ' ' + ISNULL(NULLIF ([OrderComment], ''), '') AS OrderText, 
    [gt].[GradeTypeID], 
    [g].[GradeID],
    [o].[OrderID],
    [o].[CreditIssued]
FROM ((([People] AS op 
INNER JOIN [Grades] AS g 
ON [op].[LunchTimeID] = [g].[GradeID]) 
INNER JOIN ([Meals] AS m 
INNER JOIN [Orders] AS o 
ON [m].[MealID] = [o].[MealID]) 
ON [op].[PersonID] = [o].[PersonID]) 
INNER JOIN [DrinkOptions] AS do 
ON [o].[DrinkID] = [do].[DrinkID]) 
INNER JOIN [GradeTypes] AS gt 
ON [g].[GradeTypeID] = [gt].[GradeTypeID]) a
WHERE SortNbr != 18
```

Comment: what error are you getting? what do you mean you are trying to "update" it?

Comment: This view is kind of crazy. That join syntax was either written by an automated tool or somebody who really like to makes things way more complicated than they need to be. The only difference I see between those two queries is that the first joins the People table to the People on the same value. I thought maybe it was a parent/child thing but no, it is just the same exact row that it is joining to. You could also just add the where predicate to each query and eliminate the need for the outer query entirely.

Comment: As @Dan already mentioned, views with `union` or `union all` selects *are* generally *non-updateable*. I actually create this type of view on purpose sometime.

Comment: @scsimon, the following statement works fine on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise version 11.0.6251 Windows NT 6.3 (15063), but not on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise version 11.0.3128 Windows NT 6.2 (9200): UPDATE Credits SET CreditIssued = 1 WHERE OrderID = ?"

Comment: @SeanLange, Yes, the join is tricky. The users want to see staff listed with their grades, not listed separately. So, yes the first query and the second query are very similar, but the result is correct.

Comment: I would start by getting that join syntax sorted out. As posted it is incredibly difficult to maintain because the joins are mixed together. And I suspect it could be greatly simplified.

Comment: @SeanLange The join works. The results are exactly what is needed. The update works on two versions of SQL Server

Comment: I realize they "work" but maintaining that is horrific. Get rid of all those parenthesis and get the tables and their predicates next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

For non-updateable views (e.g. `UNION ALL` construct), you need to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

Comment: The following statement works fine on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise version 11.0.6251 Windows NT 6.3 (15063), but not on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise version 11.0.3128 Windows NT 6.2 (9200): UPDATE Credits SET CreditIssued = 1 WHERE OrderID = ?". The statement also works fine on SQL Server Standard 13.0.4206.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.3